# How long does Firebase store my crash data? / Export data from Crashlytics?

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics, firebase-analytics, crashlytics-android

I have to leave my work with applications for for several months. Later, I would like to remove some of the errors that currently Crashlitics shows.

1. How long does Firebase store my data, especially crashes.
2. Is it possible to export data from Firebase Crashlytics?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks. Crashlytics stores 90 days of crash data. You will soon be able to export data directly from Firebase Crashlytics.

Comment: I have implemented a temporary solution - recorded the screen viewing the most frequent errors. It worked quite well ; )

Comment: How do you guys handle it if a user contacts your and says they want crashlytics data you collected from them deleted

Comment: Is there a way to export data directly from Firebase Crashlytics now?  Could you please share?

Comment: 2 years... and still no option to export data from Firebase Crashlytics :|